# can records be used insttead of reflection builder for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, record, builder

I have been using reflection typically composed with the builder pattern to build my domain objects in order to write unit tests (using xUnit) for my domain layer.  As I see in newer versions of C# and .net, there is a way to use records that are immutable. My question: Is it a suitable way to use "records" with the "With" method instead of those objects instantiated by my test builder which inherits the below reflection builder class (which also has a With method)?

This is my reflection builder class which I use as an abstract:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Utility.ReflectionTools
{
    public abstract class ReflectionBuilder<TReflection, TBuilder>
          where TReflection : class
          where TBuilder : ReflectionBuilder<TReflection, TBuilder>
    {
        private readonly TBuilder? _builderInstance = null;

        public ReflectionBuilder()
        {
            //store the concrete builder instance
            _builderInstance = (TBuilder)this;
        }

        private class PropertyWrapper
        {
            public PropertyInfo Property { get; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            internal PropertyWrapper(PropertyInfo property, object value)
            {
                Property = property;
                Value = value;
            }
        }

        public TBuilder With<TValue>(Expression<Func<TReflection, TValue>> exp, TValue value)
        {
            var body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (body == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Improperly formatted expression");
            }

            var propertyName = body.Member.Name;

            var property = GetType().GetRuntimeField(propertyName);

            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(_builderInstance, value);
            }
            else
            {
                GetType().GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    ?.SetValue(_builderInstance, value);
            }

            return _builderInstance!;
        }


        public abstract TReflection Build();

    }
}
```

This is my sample of testbuilder to build an instance of a domain class:

```
using Domain.Customers;
using DomainContract.Constants.Customers;
using Utility.ReflectionTools;

namespace DomainTest.Customers.TestBuilders
{
    public class CustomerDomainTestBuilder:ReflectionBuilder<CustomerDomain, CustomerDomainTestBuilder >
    {
        private CustomerDomainTestBuilder _builderInstance;

        public string FirstName = CustomerConstants.SomeFirstName;
        public string LastName = CustomerConstants.SomeLastName;
        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth = CustomerConstants.SomeDateOfBirth;
        public string PhoneNumber = CustomerConstants.SomePhoneNumber;
        public string Email = CustomerConstants.SomeEmail;
        public string BankAccountNumber = CustomerConstants.SomeBankAccountNumber;

        public CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
        {
            _builderInstance = this;
        }

        public override CustomerDomain Build()
        {
            var customerDomain = new CustomerDomain(this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.DateOfBirth, this.PhoneNumber,
                this.Email, this.BankAccountNumber);
            return customerDomain;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my domain class:

```
using Domain.Abstractions;

namespace Domain.Customers
{
    public class CustomerDomain : AggregateRoot
    {
        public string FirstName { get; private set; } = null!;
        public string LastName { get; private set; } = null!;
        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; private set; } = null!;
        public string Email { get; private set; } = null!;
        public BankAccountVo BankAccount { get; private set; } = null!;

        public CustomerDomain(string firstName, string lastName, DateTimeOffset dateOfBirth, string phoneNumber, string email, string bankAccountNumber)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
            {
                throw new Exception("First name is null,empty or white space.") { HResult = 10 };
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            {
                throw new Exception("Last name is null,empty or white space.") { HResult = 20 };
            }

            if (DateTimeOffset.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year < 12)
            {
                throw new Exception("Customer should be at least 12 years old.") { HResult = 30 };
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNumber))
            {
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber is null, empty or white space.") { HResult = 40 };
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            {
                throw new Exception("Email is null, empty or white space.") { HResult = 50 };
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bankAccountNumber))
            {
                throw new Exception("BankAccountNumber is null, empty or white space.") { HResult = 60 };
            }

            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            Email = email;
            BankAccount = new BankAccountVo(bankAccountNumber);
        }

    }
}
```

and finally, this is my tests class for mentioned domain class:

```
using Domain.Customers;
using DomainTest.Customers.TestBuilders;
using FluentAssertions;

namespace DomainTest.Customers
{
    //Todo: avoid using hard code messages for exceptions. try using constants.
    public class CustomerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void FirstName_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.FirstName, string.Empty)
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("First name is null,empty or white space.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void LastName_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.LastName, string.Empty)
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("Last name is null, empty or white space.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Customer_Should_Be_Equal_Or_Greater_Than_Twelve_years_Old()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.DateOfBirth, new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2011, 12, 25), new TimeSpan(0, 3, 30, 0)))
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("Customer should be at least 12 years old.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void PhoneNumber_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.PhoneNumber, string.Empty)
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("PhoneNumber is null, empty or white space.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Email_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.Email, string.Empty)
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("Email is null, empty or white space.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void BankAccountNumber_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            Action act = () =>
            {
                var customer = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
                    .With(x => x.BankAccount, new BankAccountVo(string.Empty))
                    .Build();
            };
            act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("BankAccountNumber is null, empty or white space.");
        }

        //Todo: due to lck of time, we did cancel adding domain contract and adding domain service of validation. it should be like that.
    }
}
```

I have not tried records as I was confused a little bit with its concept. Anyone can help me please with building my domain objects in tests using records?

Comment: I don't get the question. Records are not a drop-in replacement for classes. And secondly: why the reflection?

Comment: using reflection is because my domain objects have private set properties and builder is because I want to have the builders with builder pattern to build my domain objects via constructor but with different values of properties for test cases. For records, I have seen a "With "keyword which may be a suitable replacement for my "With "method in my reflection builder.

Comment: What is the `PropertyWrapper` used for?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be the judge for which you think is better.

This is an example of what it could look like, just converting your code.

Testbuilder:

```
public record CustomerDomainTestBuilder // <= record instead of inheritance
{
    private CustomerDomainTestBuilder _builderInstance;

    public string FirstName = CustomerConstants.SomeFirstName;
    public string LastName = CustomerConstants.SomeLastName;
    public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth = CustomerConstants.SomeDateOfBirth;
    public string PhoneNumber = CustomerConstants.SomePhoneNumber;
    public string Email = CustomerConstants.SomeEmail;
    public string BankAccountNumber = CustomerConstants.SomeBankAccountNumber;

    public CustomerDomainTestBuilder()
    {
        _builderInstance = this;
    }

    public CustomerDomain Build()
    {
        var customerDomain = new CustomerDomain(this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.DateOfBirth, this.PhoneNumber,
            this.Email, this.BankAccountNumber);
        return customerDomain;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class CustomerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void FirstName_Should_Not_Be_NullOrWhiteSpace()
    {
        Action act = () =>
        {
            var customer = (new CustomerDomainTestBuilder() with // <= Use with keyword
                    { FirstName = string.Empty })
                .Build();
        };
        act.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("First name is null,empty or white space.");
    }

    // Additional tests ...
}
```

An advantage for records could be when you want several copies of an object with just some property/-ies altered:

```
var customerbuilder = new CustomerDomainTestBuilder() with
                        {
                            FirstName = "Adam",
                            // additional setup
                        };

var customerAdam = customerBuilder.Build();
var customerBob = (customerBuilder with { FirstName = "Bob" }).Build();

// Test things with Adam and Bob ...
```

Perhaps read this for inspiration: https://josef.codes/using-records-when-implementing-the-builder-pattern-in-c-sharp/